# What is the difference between Logical and Comparison operators in MySQL?

Tags: boolean, operators, logic, terminology, relation

Studying MySQL I came to some confusion about operators categorization in MySQL.

`NOT` is a **Logical operator** [(Details)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/logical-operators.html)

while `NOT LIKE, LIKE, IS NOT, IS NULL` are **Comparison operators**. [(Details)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html)

I'm unable to grasp the real difference.

Answer (score 5):

A logical operator's operands are booleans; whereas comparison operators may have operands of any type.

The comparison operators test the *relationship* between their operands according to an *ordering* over the operands' type set, and return a boolean result: `1 < 2`, `'hello' > 'aardvark'`, `CURRENT_DATE = '2013-12-30'`, `'peanut' LIKE 'pea%'`, `'walnut' NOT LIKE 'pea%'`, `'' IS NOT NULL`, etc.

Booleans, on the other hand, don't have an "ordering" by which such relationships can be established*—it's pretty meaningless, for example, to say that `FALSE < TRUE`.  Instead, we think about them in terms of their "truth" and the operators which act upon them in terms of their logical validity: `TRUE AND TRUE`, `FALSE XOR TRUE`, `NOT FALSE`, etc.

Of course, there are many situations where the same logical result can be expressed in multiple ways—for example:

- `1 < 2` is logically the same as both `2 > 1` and `NOT (1 >= 2)`
- `'walnut' NOT LIKE 'pea%'` is logically the same as `NOT ('walnut' LIKE 'pea%')`
- `'' IS NOT NULL` is logically the same as `NOT ('' IS NULL)`

However, negating a comparison involves a logical operation (negation) in addition to the comparison operation, whereas a single comparison operation that immediately yields the desired result is typically more concise/readable and may be easier for the computer to optimise.

---

<sup>* Some languages (such as MySQL) don't have real boolean types, instead using zero and non-zero integers to represent `FALSE` and `TRUE` respectfully.  Consequently an ordering does exist over their booleans, albeit that doesn't affect the conceptual distinction.</sup>

Comment: If I say: "Comparison operators are used to compare two values and logical operators ______ ". How would you complete this sentence?

Comment: @YousufMemon: In that sentence, I'd probably change how I define comparison operators.  See my revision above.

Comment: I'm going to make this post CW, as I'm pretty sure this answer could be improved by more brilliant minds than mine.

Comment: @YousufMemon ... and logical operators perform logical operations on boolean types only.

Answer (score 1):

Simply put, `NOT LIKE, LIKE, IS NOT` are used to compare two values.  For example :

```
SELECT * FROM `table_name` WHERE `name` NOT LIKE `examplename`;
SELECT * FROM `table_name` WHERE `key_col` IS NULL;
```

`NOT`  returns the inverse of the value. It's same as `!=`, for the most part. Example :

```
SELECT * FROM `student` WHERE NOT (student_id = 1);
```

The operator returns 1 if the operand is 0 and returns 0 if the operand is nonzero. It returns NULL if the operand is NOT NULL.

Visit : [MySQL Operators](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/mysql-functions-and-operators.php)

Visit : [NOT ! Operator](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/logical-operators/not-operator.php)

Answer (score 0):

In simple words:

- Comparison operator compares 2 values in different manners as per operator used like ==, !=, >, <, >=, <= and others.
- On the other hand, Logical operator will check conditions (more than 1) returns by comparison operator and then performs the operation as per result.